# Values aren't stored in python program

Tags: python, validation, loops, input, storage

I am practicing programming exercises from my textbook in the Input Validation Chapter. I am being asked to write a program that loops the user back to the input if  the seating section isn't A, B, or C. Once a section is selected it asks the user to enter the amount of tickets sold in that section(different maximums for each section) until it is correct. Finally is calculates the revenue for the section. My code runs fine if the values are correct, but once I enter an incorrect one, then re enter it as correct it doesn't calculate the revenue. I think it is because the values aren't being stored.

Here is the code:

```
def main():
section = input('Enter desired seating section: ')

while section != 'A' and section != 'B' and section != 'C':
    print('That is invalid, enter A, B, or C')
    section = input('Enter desired seating section: ')

tickets = int(input('Enter the amount of tickets sold: '))

if section == 'A':
    if tickets >= 0 and tickets <= 300:
        getSectionA(tickets)
    else:
        while tickets < 0 or tickets > 300:
            print('Invalid, enter a value from  0 to 300')
            tickets = int(input('Enter amount of tickets sold: '))

elif section == 'B':
    if tickets >= 0 and tickets <= 500:
        getSectionB(tickets)
    else:
        while tickets < 0 or tickets > 500:
            print('Invalid, enter a value from 0 to 500')
            tickets = int(input('Enter amount of tickets sold: '))
elif section == 'C':
    if tickets >= 0 and tickets <= 200:
        getSectionC(tickets)
    else:
        while tickets < 0 or tickets > 200:
            print('Invalid, enter a value from 0 to 200')
            tickets = int(input('Enter amount of tickets sold: '))

def getSectionA(numberA):
revA = numberA * 20
print('Your section revenue is', revA)


def getSectionB(numberB):
revB = numberB * 15
print('Your section revenue is', revB)


def getSectionC(numberC):
revC = numberC * 10
print('Your 5section revenue is', revC)


main()
```

Comment: Try to follow the program flow manually. You enter "A" and "500", so now you're in the `while` loop in the `else` condition of the A section. You enter a correct value the second time, the while loop terminates, and the `else` block completes. There's no reason for the program to jump back up into the `if` section and call `getSectionA`.

Comment: @Kevin thank you. Once I included the function at the end of the loop it ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSectionA` and similar are only called when the `if` condition that checks the numerical bounds succeeds on the first input. Once you're inside the `else`, it won't go back to call `getSectionA` even when the `while` loop finishes.

Consider rewriting the code so that `getSectionA` gets called in both the `if` and `else` sections.

```
if section == 'A':
    if tickets >= 0 and tickets <= 300:
        getSectionA(tickets)
    else:
        while tickets < 0 or tickets > 300:
            print('Invalid, enter a value from  0 to 300')
            tickets = int(input('Enter amount of tickets sold: '))
        getSectionA(tickets)
```

Or better yet, consolidate the logic so that there *is* no if-else.

```
if section == 'A':
    while tickets < 0 or tickets > 300:
        print('Invalid, enter a value from  0 to 300')
        tickets = int(input('Enter amount of tickets sold: '))
    getSectionA(tickets)
```

Or better yet, write a function that will perform the input interpreting logic for you, so you don't have to rewrite it for every section:

```
def get_value(message, min_value, max_value):
    while True:
        value = int(input(message))
        if min_value <= value <= max_value:
            return value
        else:
            print("Invalid, enter a value from {} to {}".format(min_value, max_value))

#later, in `main` after getting the seating section
prompt = "Enter the amount of tickets sold: "

if section == "A":
    getSectionA(get_value(prompt, 0, 300))
if section == "B":
    getSectionB(get_value(prompt, 0, 500))
if section == "C":
    getSectionC(get_value(prompt, 0, 200))
```

And better yet, store all information specific to each section in a dict, so you don't need to write individual functions and ifs for each one:

```
#in `main` after getting the seating section
max_seats = {"A": 300, "B": 500, "C": 200}
cost_per_ticket = {"A": 20, "B": 15, "C": 10}
tickets = get_value("Enter the amount of tickets sold: ", 0, max_seats[section])
print("Your section revenue is", tickets * cost_per_ticket[section])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your 'getSection' functions are written AFTER the code that will call them. If you cut and past the 'getSection' functions before the while loop it runs fine!

Answer (score 0):

The spacing isn't correct, so it is a little hard to read. Since you are learning I will give you some tips.

You have unnecessary functions. You don't need a function for simple multiplication.

Normally you would use a switch statement instead of all of the if's, python doesn't have a switch, but it has a dictionary.

There is no need to call the same input function multiple times. Make your loops so they contain the initial input call. This can reduce a lot of code.

I made this really condensed with my style to it. Your code worked and there wasn't anything wrong with it. I just want to show you how you can condense code and save yourself time from over complicating it.

```
import sys

def calculateRevenue(section=None, tickets=None):
    """Calculate the revenue for a seating section.

    Args:
        section (str): Seating Section values (A, B, C)
        tickets (int): Number of seats sold.
    """

    while section != "A" and section != "B" and section !="C":
        if section != None: # Check if user input has been given
            print("Invalid Selection!")
        section = input('Enter desired seating section (A, B, C): ')
    # end section validation

    section_info = {
                  "A": [300, 20],
                  "B": [500, 15],
                  "C": [200, 10],
                  }.get(section)

    while tickets == None or tickets < 0 or tickets > section_info[0]:
        if tickets != None: # Check if user input has been given
            print("Invalid value! There are not that many seats available for that section!")
        tickets = int(input('Enter the amount of tickets sold: '))            
    # end tickets validation

    result = tickets * section_info[1]
    return result
# end main

def main():
    section = None
    tickets = None

    # Parse command line arguments
    cmd_line_len = len(sys.argv)
    if cmd_line_len >= 2:
        section = sys.argv[1]
    if cmd_line_len >= 3:
        tickets = int(sys.argv[2])

    result = calculateRevenue(section, tickets)
    print('Your section revenue is ', result)
# end main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This will make your code reusable and you are able to use it on the command line.